# Which would be better? One big stateless component vs Multiple little staless components

Tags: reactjs, performance

In terms of React performance which would be better alternative, use a single big stateless components or split in multiple statless components. By example I have a Post component to render a single post that won't change and it have some parts (title, cover, body).

[image: Example]

Please explain your answer, in an easy way.

Comment: The second option is better since you encapsulated your UI. It will make them more manageable, and you can probably re-use some component somewhere else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well These are the reasons according to me :

- Small Components are easier to understand, test, and maintain
- You can reuse small components in other different functional components
- Each individual component can keep its specific logic
  isolated from other components.

This is a [great article](https://www.pmg.com/blog/common-react-mistakes-monolithic-components-lack-abstraction/) if you want to understand more in detail

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the performance: the lightweight components are better since render will be done only for the component that changed, not the entire left side's Post.

I also agree with @Kerry Gougeon comment about reuse and maintenance. Forget about the slight performance difference, implementing the left side is bad for maintenance, it is much easier to test the lightweight components: when you have a problem it will be much faster to find it. Read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html.

Answer (score 1):

Small components hands down.

First and foremost, they are easier to test. Secondly, they are easier to reuse. Thirdly, it is good to get in the mindset that components are very lightweight. This is one of the main points of React. Small lightweight reusable components.